# easiest way to add logging support in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In `play framework 2.x`, what would be the best way to add logging support in each `Action` method inside a `Controller`? Writing an extended/subclassed `Action` or something else?

Comment: What do you mean by logging support? You can use Logger.error(...) to log an error directly from a controller.

Comment: but i don't want to put the same logging activities repetitively for all Action methods. I want to be able to exact the common logging out somewhere.

Comment: I'd recommend to provide a piece of code showing what do you mean by common logging. When and what do you log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ActionBuilder` to create a `LoggingAction` (here's how: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaActionsComposition).

However, since you said "each `Action`", I assume you want to log every request. The easiest way is to use a Filter. They've implemented an example `LoggingFilter` in the docs: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/ScalaHttpFilters